# Passing link parameters via sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to insert an image link into a file for a wiki on a remote server.

```
ssh root@10.10.10.1 "sed -i -e '1i'[^http://10.10.10.2/image.jpg^]'\'" /var/www/wiki/page
```

Works but I need to add the resize parameter after the file name but it doesn't work, how do I account for the spaces?

```
ssh root@10.10.10.1 "sed -i -e '1i'[^http://10.10.10.2/image.jpg height480 width=640^]'\'" /var/www/wiki/page
sed: can't read height480: No such file or directory
sed: can't read width=640^]\: No such file or directory
```

Comment: maybe you can do like this image.jpg\ height480\ width ?

Comment: That worked many thanks, i've been trying man combinations of quotes and ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're quoting only the '1i'. You should quote the entire sed expression, if you have spaces in it. Try this:

```
ssh root@10.10.10.1 "sed -i -e '1i[^http://10.10.10.2/image.jpg height480 width=640^]'" /var/www/wiki/page
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use `heredoc` here to avoid crazy escaping and other issues like spaces in command:

```
ssh -t -t root@10.10.10.1 <<'EOF'
sed -i '1i[^http://10.10.10.2/image.jpg height480 width=640^]' /var/www/wiki/page
exit
EOF
```